# Why does %matplotlib inline in Repl.it give me an error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, inline, replit

I'm trying to create a word cloud using Repl.it by following this towards data science article. However, I'm getting an error with %matplotlib inline (underlined in red). How do I fix this?

```
# Import packages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Define a function to plot word cloud
def plot_cloud(wordcloud):
    # Set figure size
    plt.figure(figsize=(40, 30))
    # Display image
    plt.imshow(wordcloud) 
    # No axis details
    plt.axis("off");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is you're using what are called magic commands (and not to be confused with magic method which is an informal synonym for [special method](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=magic%20methods#term-special-method)). More specifically in this case [line magics](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/iteractive/magics.html#line-magics). There are also cell magics.

Line (and cell) magics are not common to all of python but rather to ipython and (by extension) jupyter notebooks.

To create a word cloud in a notebook that isn't on your own desktop, you'll need a platform that is able to run an notebook. Something like [binder](https://mybinder.org/) or Google [Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/) though there certainly others.

Answer (score 0):

NoNameByProgram from repl.it, and it's because it actually is a `SyntaxError`. You can fix this by deleting `%matplotlib inline`. It will not change the code's effect.

Answer (score 0):

%matplotlib.inline is a command for Jupyter Notebook. For IDLE simply write your plotting code, without the inline command, and it should be able to produce the plot.